# grouping: being part of a department twice

Tags: pyspark, grouping

I have employee data and want to find out, if some persons worked twice or more times in a department or not.

The data looks as follows:

```
emp_id      begin       end         dept_id
 1. 07a0fcf5    30.06.2021  30.06.2021  1443
 2. 07a0fcf5    01.07.2021  01.07.2021  1443
 3. 07a0fcf5    02.07.2021  02.07.2021  1269
 4. 07a0fcf5    03.07.2021  11.07.2021  1269
 5. 07a0fcf5    12.07.2021  14.07.2021  1269
 6. 07a0fcf5    15.07.2021  15.07.2021  1273
 7. 07a0fcf5    16.07.2021  30.08.2021  1273
 8. 07a0fcf5    31.08.2021  05.10.2021  1273
 9. 07a0fcf5    06.10.2021  21.02.2022  1269
 10. 07a0fcf5   24.02.2022  23.06.2022  1269
 11. 07a0fcf5   24.06.2022  01.01.9999  1269
 12. 07d06bee   28.06.2021  29.06.2021  1273  
 13. 07d06bee   30.06.2021  30.06.2021  1287
 14. 07d06bee   01.07.2021  26.07.2021  1443
 15. 07d06bee   27.07.2021  27.07.2021  1287
 16. 07d06bee   28.07.2021  01.08.2021  1443
 17. 07d06bee   02.08.2021  01.01.9999  1287
 18. 07d1fdd3   25.05.2021  25.05.2021  1256
 19. 07d1fdd3   26.05.2021  26.05.2021  1256
 20. 07d1fdd3   27.05.2021  27.05.2021  1256
 21. 07d1fdd3   28.05.2021  06.06.2021  1256
 22. 07d1fdd3   07.06.2021  18.06.2021  1256
 23. 07d1fdd3   19.06.2021  20.06.2021  1256
 24. 07d1fdd3   21.06.2021  21.06.2021  1256
 25. 07d1fdd3   22.06.2021  06.07.2021  1256
 26. 07d1fdd3   07.07.2021  13.07.2021  1098
 27. 07d1fdd3   14.07.2021  16.08.2021  1098
 28. 07d1fdd3   17.08.2021  25.08.2021  1098
 29. 07d1fdd3   26.08.2021  26.08.2021  1098
 30. 07d1fdd3   27.08.2021  06.09.2021  1098
```

Thus, the desired result is something like this:

```
emp_id      dept_id     times_worked
 1. 07a0fcf5    1443        1 
 2. 07a0fcf5    1269        2 
 3. 07a0fcf5    1273        1
 4. 07d06bee    1273        1 
 5. 07d06bee    1287        3 
 6. 07d06bee    1443        2
 7. 07d1fdd3    1256        1 
 8. 07d1fdd4    1098        1
```

Of course, the aggregation itself is not the problem, but I want to find out how to handle the several appearances of `dept_ids` in the raw data. As I have to use pySpark in a cloud environment with several executors, sorting makes it impossible to check the content of the different data lines as the data is spread over the executors. I already tried the window function, but with no useful result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard for us to debug your code if you don't show that to us, thus please [edit] the question with an [mre].

Comment: how are you calculating the `times_worked`? it does not look like a straight count

Comment: to be honest I calculated it manually right now. The solution does not has to be exactly like this but close to it, in order to see, how many times the person was working for the department.

Comment: but how would you tell the emp worked more than once? is it just a count of their records? if yes, group by emp and dept columns and take a count of records

Comment: Welcome to my problem: if I group by emp and dept, then I do not see that the first emp has worked twice for 1269 in different time spans. But that is exactly what I want to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are trying to do. The count only increases if they actually change department. I think you can do this with a window, check if the dept_id changes, and then sum the changes?

I think this will be easier with [Fugue](https://fugue-tutorials.readthedocs.io/tutorials/quick_look/ten_minutes.html) though which lets you port Python and Pandas code to Spark or Dask. Let's concern ourselves with one employee. The logic will look like this in Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"emp_id": ["07d06bee"] * 6,
                   "begin": ["28.06.2021", "30.06.2021", "01.07.2021", "27.07.2021", "28.07.2021", "02.08.2021"],
                   "end": ["29.06.2021", "30.06.2021", "26.07.2021", "27.07.2021", "01.08.2021", "01.01.9999"],
                   "dept_id": [1273, 1287, 1443, 1287, 1443, 1287]})

def one_emp_count(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # replace 01.01.9999 with end of year because it's not a valid datetime
    df["end"] = df["end"].replace("01.01.9999", "31.12.2022")
    # convert to datetime
    df['begin'] = pd.to_datetime(df['begin'], format="%d.%m.%Y")
    df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'], format="%d.%m.%Y")
    # sort partition to guarantee order
    df = df.sort_values("end", inplace=False)
    # calculate change
    df["last_dept"] = df["dept_id"].shift(1)
    df["change_dept"] = (df["dept_id"] != df["last_dept"]).astype(int)
    # construct result
    res = df.groupby("dept_id").agg({"change_dept": sum}).reset_index()
    res["emp_id"] = df.iloc[0]["emp_id"]
    return res[["emp_id", "dept_id", "change_dept"]]
```

This gives me:

```
    emp_id  dept_id change_dept
0   07d06bee    1273    1
1   07d06bee    1287    3
2   07d06bee    1443    2
```

We can then bring it to Spark with Fugue using the `transform()` function

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)

from fugue import transform
res = transform(sdf, 
                one_emp_count, 
                schema="emp_id:str, dept_id:int, change_dept:int", 
                partition={"by": "emp_id"}, 
                engine=spark)
res.show()
```

This will apply the `one_emp_count` function on each partition where each partition is one employee id. If the engine is `None`, it will run on Pandas. By passing the `SparkSession` to the engine, it will run on Spark.